# iOS Push Notifications - no push after delete and reinstall

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have (had) a working push in my App, which is in Development and could send pushes from a PHP Script which are stored in a Database, after the App launches.
But after disabling and reenabling push in den Message-Center (tested on iPhone) or deleting and reinstalling (tested on iPad) the App, I'm not able to push to these devices again. I received new tokens for those devices and deleted the old tokens from my Database.

My php Script for receiving the tokens that can be deleted (feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196) does not return any information to me, although the connection seems to be fine.

I do call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]  registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
    (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
    UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
    UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

every time the app launches, and the app always registers smoothly in

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)aDeviceToken;
```

I can see it because I have a NSLog at that point, which shows the token

Here's my code:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"Registered device with token %@", deviceToken); //Here i'm writing token into Database if not exists
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Registering device failed: %@", error);
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: It seems more like a backend issue to me. Try to see if any duplicates in your database for the UDID of your device. also why deleting existing records and creating new ones? Simply return existing token for this UDID if already in databse, if record doesn't exist then run your insert statement.

Comment: I only have 2 entries at the moment, because im figuring out how to handle that push stuff. These 2 entries are my iPhone and my iPad. The Tokens that are in my database are the same i can see in my AppDelegate.m when the devices register (NSLog entry).

Answer (score 0):

you should ask for push registration every time the app finish launching like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

then check if the callback returns to this function:

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)aDeviceToken;
```

or to this function:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

if it fails to register check why and comment please

Comment: I do call 
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];` every time the app launches, and the app always registers smoothly in
`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)aDeviceToken;`. I can see it because i habe a NSLog at that point, wichs shows the token.

Comment: Yes i do. And the push script uses the database with the recent tokens

Comment: I also sended pushes to the old tokens, to force the feedback server to give me the deprecated tokens, but feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196 does not deliver any token back.

Comment: i just figured out that the FIRST token (i found it in the APN-Tester App for OSX) that was added to the database for my iPhone is still working, although the app tells me it uses a new token. So whats that????

Comment: try to unregister first and then to reregister

Comment: unregister? how do i unregister? i thought the app unregisters it self at the push server, and thats the reason why there is a feedback server! I think i read about the problem of Apps with "unregistered" tokens and the only way to get them is to ask the feedback server.